# Распарсить строку String и представить ее в виде XML, не создавая файлов

Tags: xml, xmlparser, java

Всем привет! Имеется php-скрипт, отсылающий на определенный порт определенного сервера XML-запрос методом POST. На серверной стороне присутствует java-демон, принимающий запросы по данному адресу. В итоге, я получаю строку, например, такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><robox.rate.req><in_curr>EGZ</in_curr><out_curr>WMZ</out_curr><merchant_login>login</merchant_login><out_cnt>1</out_cnt></robox.rate.req>
```

Без пробелов, табуляций и переносов строк. Я читал про парсеры XML (SAX, JAXP), они хороши, но работают лишь с файлами .xml . Возможно ли распарсить строку какими-то библиотеками, которые удобно бы представили структуру XML-запроса и методы для работы с ними? Или придется вручную выковыривать значения из треугольных скобок, работать со строкой? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неожиданно, я кое-что нагуглил:

```
private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder;  
    try 
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlStr ) ) ); 
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    return null;
}
```